# PHP SoapClient removing element with name

Tags: php, soap-client

I have a WSDL that has an element that requires an attribute:

```
<xsd:complexType name="claim">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Claim Element</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <!-- other elements removed -->
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="claimId" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

In terms of generated xml, it should look like:

```
<claims>
    <claim claimId="1">
        <!-- elements removed -->
    </claim>
    <!-- more claims -->
</claims>
```

Within a `foreach` loop I am putting together an array of elements and using the attribute as part of the key:

```
//$claim = array of key/value pairs
$claim = [...];
$claim = new \SoapVar($claim, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'claim claimId="' . ($key+1) . '"');
$claims['claim claimId="'.($key+1).'"'] = $claim;
```

When it comes to passing this to the SoapClient, the elements get removed:

```
//$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl);
$client->checkClaims($claims);
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
<claims />
```

How do I get my soap client to parse the `claim` elements correctly in the soap call?

Comment: Can you show code with sample values added to it?

Comment: can you post a dummy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that `\SoapClient` can accept an xml string, I decided to convert my array of data into an xml string:

```
/**
 * Convert an array to an xml. Recursive function.
 * @param array $array
 * @param String $rootElement OPTIONAL name of root element.
 * @param \Simple XMLElement $xml OPTIONAL
 * @return String
 */
function arrayToXml($array, $rootElement = null, $xml = null) {
    $_xml = $xml;

    if ($_xml === null) {
        $_xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($rootElement !== null ? $rootElement : '<root/>');
    }

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) { //nested array
            arrayToXml($v, $k, $_xml->addChild($k));
      } else {
            $_xml->addChild($k, $v);
      }
    }
    //Remove xml doctype and root name spaces.
    return str_replace(["<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n", '<root>', "</root>\n"], '', $_xml->asXML());
}

//my array of claims
$claims = [
    'claim claimId="1"' => [
        //...
    ],
    'claim claimId="2"' => [
        //...
    ],
    //...
];
$claims = arrayToXml($claims);
```

This generates an xml string of:

```
<claim claimId="1"><!-- stuff --></claim claimId="1"><claim claimId="2"><!-- stuff --></claim claimId="2">
```

Next step is to remove the attribute from the closing tags:

```
$claims = preg_replace('#</claim claimId="\d+">#', '</claim>', $claims);
```

Finally, I wrap my xml in the appropriate parameter name and convert it to a `\SoapVar` so the `\SoapClient` will parse it correctly:

```
$claims = '<ns1:claims>' . $claims . '</ns1:claims>';
$claims = new \SoapVar($claims, XSD_ANYXML, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
```

Passing `$claims` into my `\SoapClient` and running `var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());` shows my generated xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:claims><claim claimId="1"><!--stuff--></claim><claim claimId="2"><!--stuff--></claim></ns1:claims></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Just as it wanted.

Answer (score 2):

So there are few issues with your code. For this to work, you need to use the SoapClient in WSDL mode (`$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl);`, which you are doing). Next below is wrong

```
$claim = [...];
$claim = new \SoapVar($claim, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'claim claimId="' . ($key+1) . '"');
$claims['claim claimId="'.($key+1).'"'] = $claim;
```

You don't add attributes using `'claim claimId="' . ($key+1) . '"'`.

Now what you need is to use a `classmap`. Below is a sample python flask app I created to show the `WSDL`

```
from flask import Flask

app  = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/ICalculator",methods=['get', 'post'])
def reply():
    return "<xmldata />"

@app.route("/app.wsdl")
def send():
    return """<wsdl:definitions
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
  xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
  xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
  xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
  xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
  xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" targetNamespace="http://localhost:5001"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost:5001" elementFormDefault="qualified" >
    <xsd:element name="Claim">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="a" type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="b" type="xsd:int" />
      </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="claimId" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="AddResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="result" type="xsd:int" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ICalculator_Add_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Add" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ICalculator_Add_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AddResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ICalculator">
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://localhost:5001/ICalculator/Add" message="tns:ICalculator_Add_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://localhost:5001/ICalculator/AddResponse" message="tns:ICalculator_Add_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="DefaultBinding_ICalculator" type="tns:ICalculator">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:5001/ICalculator/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CalculatorService">
        <wsdl:port name="ICalculator" binding="tns:DefaultBinding_ICalculator">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:5001/ICalculator" /></wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
""".replace(r"\r", "").replace(r"\n", "")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Then ran the same using

```
python3 wsdl.py
```

And ran another `socat` to view the traffic

```
socat -v TCP-LISTEN:5001,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:5000
```

Next I wrote a sample PHP code to show how `classmap` works

```
<?php
class Claim {
  public function __construct(Array $properties=array()){
      foreach($properties as $key => $value){
        $this->{$key} = $value;
      }
    }
}

$test = new Claim(array('claimId'=>10, 'a'=> 22, 'b'=> 33));

$claim=new SoapVar($test, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$wsdl = "http://localhost:5001/app.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'trace'        => 1,
    'encoding'     => 'UTF-8',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'classmap'     => array('Claim' => 'Claim')
));
$client->add($claim);
```

And the resultant `xml` is

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:5001" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Body><parameters claimId="10" xsi:type="ns1:Claim"><ns1:a>22</ns1:a><ns1:b>33</ns1:b></parameters></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

[image: Data as attributes]

References:

[PHP soap request with an element attribute and child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573680/php-soap-request-with-an-element-attribute-and-child-elements)

[PHP SoapVar Object Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223896/php-soapvar-object-attribute)

[Adding attributes to the actual function tag in PHP soapCall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481095/adding-attributes-to-the-actual-function-tag-in-php-soapcall)

[How do I add additional attributes to XML Elements with the SoapClient Class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061982/how-do-i-add-additional-attributes-to-xml-elements-with-the-soapclient-class-in)

[php SoapVar not setting attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870910/php-soapvar-not-setting-attributes)

[Getting the XML as string for a SoapVar variable - without a webservice (locally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207403/getting-the-xml-as-string-for-a-soapvar-variable-without-a-webservice-locally?lq=1)

[Getting the XML as string for a SoapVar variable - without a webservice (locally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207403/getting-the-xml-as-string-for-a-soapvar-variable-without-a-webservice-locally)

http://fvue.nl/wiki/Php:_Soap:_How_to_add_attribute_to_SoapVar

https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/137357-solved-php-soap-client-node-attributes/

http://eosrei.net/articles/2012/01/php-soap-xml-attributes-namespaces-xmlwriter

Comment: I've tried something like this already, using the Wsdl2PhpGenerator. I learned that the soap server is very literal in what it expects. The generated xml has to be as I posted.

Comment: So what is the issue my approach?